# Flex event.bytesLoaded returning wrong value

Tags: apache-flex

I have a function that's called when a file download has reported progress:

```
        private function progressHandler(event:ProgressEvent):void
        {
            var percent:Number = Math.round((event.bytesLoaded / event.bytesTotal) * 100.0);
            Alert.show(event.bytesLoaded.toString());
            //pb.setProgress(percent, 100);
        }
```

Now, this should work fine but unfortunately, event.bytesLoaded is returning much larger values than it should.  For a test file (8555 bytes), bytesLoaded goes all the way up to 8973384.

Any ideas why this might be happening?

Comment: Is the file 8555 kilobytes - because the number you gave is close to 8555 * 1024

Comment: That's... something I hadn't thought of - lemme look at it and get back to you (but why would one (event.bytesTotal) return in KB and the other (event.bytesLoaded) return the straight number of bytes?)

Comment: I'm not sure why they return different things, but I changed it to var percent:Number = Math.round(((event.bytesLoaded/1024) / event.bytesTotal) * 100.0); and it works close enough now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amarghosh, in his comment, gave the hint that lead to a solution.

"Is the file 8555 kilobytes - because the number you gave is close to 8555 * 1024"